# How to check subsets efficiently

Tags: algorithms

Suppose we have a 5-bit 0-1 string "01001" and a set of 5-bit 0-1 strings {"01010","10111","01011"}. Define a relation on string a and b: $a \subseteq b$ if and only if all bits 1 in a exist in b in the same position. For example. 01001$\subseteq$01011 because all bits 1 in 01001 also exist in 01011 in the same position. Here is the question: Could we design a pattern, like a encoding function F($a$,$S$) to use bit operation to encode all strings in the string set $S$, such that whenever a new string $a$ comes, we can check whether $a$ is a subset of one of the string in the string set $S$ in $\textbf{one operation}$, $\textbf{in which we don't need to iterative every element in S}$. We just need to know whether it is a subset and we don't care which set is $a$'s superset. In the example, F(01001,{01010,10111,01011}) = 1 because 01001 is a subset of one element in {01010,10111,01011}.

Comment: If your string sequences are $n$-bit long you can construct a binary tree that checks for every bit whether there's still a string in your sequence that matches it. That way the checking part is only $n$ operations at most, but you'll need a binary tree with up to $2^n$ nodes.

Comment: Yes I think binary tree is a good idea. But the space complexity is a little big. :)

Comment: In reality the space complexity wouldn't be that big because you would be able to do quite a lot of pruning. In your example, after prunning your tree would only have 5 leaves instead of 32.

Comment: It would look like this:
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right. \\
        \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right. \\ 1\end{array}\right.
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

To check if $a \subseteq b$ you can check whether $a \& b =a$. Therefore you can try something like
$$F(a,S)=OR_{b \in S} (a\&b=a)$$

Comment: Yes but I want to design a encoding method. In your way, we need to do n OR operations, in which n is the size of S. But I want to think out a way that we just need to do one operation, so that we can check.

Comment: you can use early stopping when doing the OR operations. But the worst case complexity will always be linear in $n$